# Extending a native NiFi processor

Tags: java, apache-nifi

I already know how to write a custom Processor (extending `org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor`).  I've used this technique and I'm comfortable creating custom `org.apache.nifi.components.PropertyDescriptor` & `org.apache.nifi.processor.Relationship` fields, as well as overriding the `onTrigger` method.  In addition, I know how to setup the build, establish the Manifest and create my `.nar` file.

What I haven't been able to figure out is whether there is a reasonable pattern for extending a native NiFi processor.  My hope is to extend a native processor so that I can use my extended class (rather than other classes) for new Unit Tests.

At a minimum, all I want to do is extend a processor and set the value for a particular `PropertyDescriptor` that it defines.  Gold-plating might be preventing a user (e.g. via the NiFi canvas) from changing this configuration.

Can anyone provide any guidance or provide some reference material?

Thanks!

---

***Additional detail*** : My specific goal is to set the value of the `JOLT_SPEC` in the native [JoltTransformJSON processor](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/rel/nifi-1.5.0/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-bundle/nifi-standard-processors/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/standard/JoltTransformJSON.java#L95-L102).  Although, I'm hoping that there is a convention for setting `PropertyDescriptor` values beyond this specific class & field.

Comment: For clarification, when you say extend, do you want the change you make to override the existing native processor?

Comment: I'd like the change to be scoped to my subclass only.  However, if sub-classing is an anti-pattern here, I'm open to other techniques.

Comment: So are you attempting to set a default value for the JoltTransform processor?

Comment: Yes, but I'd really like understand the viability of such a pattern.  In this particular case, I want to create a various pre-configured classes that set different values for this one property.  For example, I might create sub-classes of `JoltTransformJSON processor` and are defined as `MyTransformTweetTimestampProcessor` or `MyTransformTweetLocationProcessor`.  These example classes would each set a different value.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing stopping you from building a NAR with subclassed special implementations with these custom behaviors, but to me it sounds unnecessary. You're not extending the functionality of these processors with new behavior, you're just pre-configuring values and restricting access. Both of these steps can be done with native NiFi functionality.

I would suggest looking at the [API](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/rest-api/index.html) or using a tool like [NiFi CLI](https://github.com/apache/nifi/tree/master/nifi-toolkit/nifi-toolkit-cli) or [NiPyAPI](https://nipyapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html) to script this behavior -- read the `JOLT_SPEC` from a static resource, provide it as the `PropertyDescriptor` value, and set the ACL on the processor to be read-only for specific users.

Comment: Actually my question is : is it possible to create a customized niti processor wich extens a from a satndard nifi processor ??

Comment: Yes, make a new Maven module for your processor, depend on `nifi-standard-processors`, and then in your code extend the processor (e.g. `public class CustomizedEncryptContent extends EncryptContent {}`).